# Ubuntu 22.04/20.04 kfd kfd: amdgpu: TAHITI not supported in kfd

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, xorg, 22.04

So, I followed the steps at this link and added that repository:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html.en

I was on 20.04.  After running sudo apt update && apt upgrade, this partially upgraded my system and broke some things.  I then edited the /etc/apt/sources.list file and changed all instances of "focal" to "jammy" in an attempt to fix the situation, as the opposite did not work.  After many packages installed, my machine now boots into TTY and the message in the title appears.  Changing all the repositories back to focal did not fix it, at least not by subsequently running sudo apt update && apt upgrade.  startx fails and this error (EE) is in the log file:

open /dev/fb0: Permission denied

I tried following the steps at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149985/startx-cannot-open-dev-fb0-permission-denied but I couldn't edit the file in question because it was read-only.

I recall some shenanigans with getting my GPU (AMD Radeon R9 280) to work with 20.04 a couple of years ago, and updating must've undone that.

In short--I screwed up my 20.04 installation by adding 22.04 repositories.  How can I roll everything back or otherwise remedy the situation?

Comment: If you've installed multiple *jammy* (22.04) packages on your system, the easiest way back to *focal* (20.04) is to restore data from your backups. Package tools have automatic features to go to later/newer versions; but going backwards is very manual, and restoration from backups is easiest. You didn't say if you're using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop or Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, but you can re-install the Desktop system without destroying your data (*re-use partitions & don't format*)

Comment: @guiverc I am using the Desktop edition.  I have backups with the built in Deja Dup backup tool, but how would I use this without a working DE?  It also only backs up my home folder.  I tried to reinstall 20.04, but because my PC now identifies as 22.04, it won't reinstall without wiping the system.  I could try installing 22.04 from disk, but I fear this may cause more harm than good.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop should install on the system, use the *Something else* option, select your existing partition(s) and do **not** format any, which will trigger a non-destructive re-install, including attempt to re-install your *manually installed* packages (if available from Ubuntu repositories, ie. software you added from Ubuntu repos will auto re-install; no guarantees on 3rd party software though as tool was for official packages only).

Comment: Why did that fail with 20.04?  There are cases with older encryption (*no longer used; eg. Ubuntu 17.10 installs offered encrypted home that isn't available by default now, but installation of a package prior to starting `ubiquity` (the installer) will resolve this (*modern releases use a better encryption method which is why the older method was dropped from default*), but without clear details we're limited in what we can offer.  If you want help with Deja Dup restoration, you'll best be getting help from others (*I don't use it sorry*)

Comment: @guiverc Why did what fail?  I am going to try the "Something else" option like you said.  Should I choose to install on the drive as a whole, or just the partition labeled "Ubuntu 22.04.1"?  There's a 500MB fat 32 partition I believe is related to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

@guiverc 's solution "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop should install on the system, use the Something else option, select your existing partition(s) and do not format any, which will trigger a non-destructive re-install, including attempt to re-install your manually installed packages (if available from Ubuntu repositories, ie. software you added from Ubuntu repos will auto re-install; no guarantees on 3rd party software though as tool was for official packages only)." worked.